# Heroku scheduled job returns 'command not found' but works with a rake

Tags: heroku, scheduled-tasks, http-get

I have a Heroku scheduled job that is supposed to run every 10 minutres. It simply makes a HTTP GET request to a controller's action which does something.

```
desc "This task is called by the Heroku scheduler add-on"
task :send_notifications => :environment do

   response = HTTParty.get('http://sendnotificationapp.com/sms/send_notifications')

end
```

When I do a rake, the task operates and functions properly:

```
heroku rake send_notifications
```

Though when I use the Heroku scheduler GUI to set it to run every 10 minutes, it doesn't operate. Instead I get the following error:

```
Starting process with command `send_notifications` by scheduler@addons.heroku.com
Starting process with command `send_notifications`
bash: send_notifications: command not found
Process exited with status 127
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sounds like you set up the Heroku scheduler job to be `send_notifications`, rather than `rake send_notifications` or `bundle exec rake send_notifications`.